# How can I write a symfony bundle which relies on Doctrine and provides entities?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am trying to write a mail-queue bundle for storing e-mail events into a location and retreive them later and process them, as we do not use a service like mandrill or likewise.

That for (and my exact usecase is not of real interest here), I like to provide additional entities in my bundle, as my bundle ships a BufferedDatabaseMailQueue.

Due to some research I included the following (yet untested) lines in the config.yml of my bundle:

```
doctrine:
orm:
    auto_mapping: false
    mappings:
       AcmeDemoBundle:
          type: annotation
          alias: MyMailQueueBundle
          prefix: MyMailQueueBundle\Entity
          dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/MyMailQueueBundle/Entity
          is_bundle: true
```

Anyways I end up with this error message:

> InvalidArgumentException in YamlFileLoader.php line 404: There is no
>   extension able to load the configuration for "doctrine"

Research indicated, that the [PrependExtensionInterface](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/prepend_extension.html) might somehow help me. But I do not know how to correctly use and configure it. So that my Bundle can be based on doctrine.

How do I do that?

Comment: Typically this sort of stuff would go in the application's config.yml.

Comment: Ok but where the Bundle XY stores entities is an bundle interna is not it?

Comment: Most bundles asks the user to add these lines in config.yml. See step3 here : https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed it using this code:

```
<?php

namespace AltergearMailQueueBundle;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DoctrineOrmMappingsPass;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
class MyMailQueueBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        /*
         * To extend the bundle to work with mongoDB and couchDB you can follow this tutorial
         * http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/mapping_model_classes.html
         * */

        parent::build($container);
        $ormCompilerClass = 'Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DoctrineOrmMappingsPass';

        if (class_exists($ormCompilerClass))
        {

            $namespaces = array( 'MyMailQueueBundle\Entity' );
            $directories = array( realpath(__DIR__.'/Entity') );
            $managerParameters = array();
            $enabledParameter = false;
            $aliasMap = array('MyMailQueueBundle' => 'MyMailQueueBundle\Entity');
            $container->addCompilerPass(
                DoctrineOrmMappingsPass::createAnnotationMappingDriver(
                        $namespaces,
                        $directories,
                        $managerParameters,
                        $enabledParameter,
                        $aliasMap
                )
            );
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought about leaving a comment, but it would be way too long, so I decided to post this as a separate answer.

First, obviously, if you're using attributes instead of annotations, use `DoctrineOrmMappingsPass::createAttributeMappingDriver` instead of `DoctrineOrmMappingsPass::createAnnotationMappingDriver`.

Second, if you use the code as is, composer will fail with the following error:

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!  
!!  In NotSupported.php line 31:
!!                                                                                 
!!    Context: Using short namespace alias "MyMailQueueBundle" by calling Doctrine\O  
!!    RM\Configuration::addEntityNamespace                                         
!!    Problem: Feature was deprecated in doctrine/persistence 2.x and is not supp  
!!    orted by installed doctrine/persistence:3.x                                  
!!    Solution: See the doctrine/deprecations logs for new alternative approaches
!!
```

The reason for this is `aliasMap` being set by OP in his answer.

Third, I heavily utilize Domain-Driven Design (DDD) and my entities are separated in their own folders. Defining them in `$directories` works fine.

So the refined solution for Symfony 6.3 would be this:

```
<?php

namespace AltergearMailQueueBundle;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DoctrineOrmMappingsPass;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
class MyMailQueueBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        /*
         * To extend the bundle to work with mongoDB and couchDB you can follow this tutorial
         * http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/mapping_model_classes.html
         * */

        parent::build($container);
        $ormCompilerClass = 'Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DoctrineOrmMappingsPass';

        if (class_exists($ormCompilerClass))
        {

            $namespaces = ['MyMailQueueBundle',];
            $directories = [
                realpath(__DIR__.'/User/Entity'),
                realpath(__DIR__.'/Common/Entity'),
                realpath(__DIR__.'/SomeOtherDir/Entity'),
            ];
            $managerParameters = array();
            $enabledParameter = false;
            $aliasMap = [];
            $container->addCompilerPass(
                DoctrineOrmMappingsPass::createAnnotationMappingDriver(
                        $namespaces,
                        $directories,
                        $managerParameters,
                        $enabledParameter,
                        $aliasMap,
                )
            );
        }


    }
}
```

Works for me just fine now.